# How do I make sure two objects don't have the same coordinates in Java?

Tags: java, comparison, coordinates

I have to write a method that makes sure two objects are not on each other position-wise. The coordinates of these objects have to be randomly generated.

My idea is a while-loop with getX() & getY() methods, that generates new coordinates till the two objects are not on the same spot.

Like this:

```
int x = getRandom(x);
int y = getRandom(y);
while(object1.getX() == object2.getX() && object1.getY() == object2.getY()){
    int x = getRandom(min, max);
    int y = getRandom(min, max);
}
```

The code works most of the time. I don't get any error messages, but in the interaction window it can be seen that the rule is not always applied. Does someone maybe have an idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not changing the coordinates of object1 or object2 inside the while loop, so it is useless, and if you enter it you will never exit

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct, but you don't have two objects but one object and a pair of int variables. You can use a do-while-loop to shorten the code a bit:

```
int x, y;
do {
    x = getRandom(min, max);
    y = getRandom(min, max);
} while (x == object.getX() && y == object.getY());
```

When the loop terminates, point (x,y) is guaranteed to be different from point (object.getX(), object.getY()).

Of course, it would be better to use proper abstractions like e. g. `Point` to represent a pair of coordinates.

Comment: I get an NullPointerException saying that the method getX() can't invoke while object is null, if I do it like this

Comment: got it. I could fix it. There was something wrong with the initialization of the object.